# Add Oauth2 scopes (Keycloak implementation) to request header before client Authorization request fires (Sring boot + Keycloak)

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, keycloak

I'm using keycloak as an auth server, my client app is a sring-boot one with the keycloak client adapter dependency.

One challenge I have not yet tackled, is the insertion of specific scopes on the request header before an authorization request executes (towards the auth server - keycloak auth endpoint).

Right now I've tested my endpoints (using access-tokens with limited capabilities by the use of scopes ) via curl and/or postman and they behave as expected, so I know they work. But I don't know when/how can I append them as a "scope" request header when using spring boot (mainly because that's all plumbing code that runs under the hood in spring boot).

I assume I would need to use some kind of interceptor/filter that gives me access to that request object just before "executing", but I haven't been able to find a concrete example.

Any suggestion/guidance or pointing towards relevant documentation would be greatly appreciated.

thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

Since my last post; I've tested several combinations to achieve this, and sadly none have worked, it is quite amazing that something as basic to oAuth2 like injecting scopes on the authorization request, isn't supported easily out of the box by the spring boot keycloak adapter. I've tried following approaches:

1 - Using a custom implementation of Sping "ClientHttpRequestInterceptor" . This doesn't help because this interceptor provides access to the front-channel requests (or requests reaching the app through the front-controller), it doesn't provide access to the back-channel request (of which the auth-request is part of).

2 - "ClientHttpRequestInterceptor" is usually also used in conjunction with a "RestTemplate" custom implementation. The problem here is that this would work only to those requests executed through an instance of the RestTemplate, and this is not what happens with the back-channel requests used by the spring-adapter

3 - Using Configuration objects based on springsecurity. spring-security offers usefull filters for configuration components that could help here (@Configuration, @EnableWebSecurity, @ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = KeycloakSecurityComponents.class OR @KeycloakConfiguration); This global type of configuration basically mix your spring boot keycloak adapter app with springsecurity code, and while this works fine for most cases, if you happen to use/need "policies" (By using the "keycloak.policy-enforcer-config" type of configs), then your policies will stop working, and whole set of new issues will arise.

FROM: https://oauth.net/2/scope/
OAuth Scopes
tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6479#section-3.3

> Scope is a mechanism in OAuth 2.0 to limit an application's access to
>   a user's account. An application can request one or more scopes, this
>   information is then presented to the user in the consent screen, and
>   the access token issued to the application will be limited to the
>   scopes granted.
>
> The OAuth spec allows the authorization server or user to modify the
>   scopes granted to the application compared to what is requested,
>   although there are not many examples of services doing this in
>   practice.
>
> OAuth does not define any particular values for scopes, since it is
>   highly dependent on the service's internal architecture and needs.

It is clearly stated that scopes can be requested by the application to receive tokens with limited access, yet all on-line documentation to achieve this with the keyclock adpaters (and particularly spring boot) is almost(completely?) non existant.

some redhat's keycloak expert could offer suggesstion?